# Java 1.7ea: Files.probeContentType(path) returns null

Tags: java, linux, nio

I'm having a bit of a strange problem with an application using the Files.probeContentType(path)-method to test for file type: On both my Ubuntu and Fedora systems, it works fine, but when moved to a RedHat Enterprise server (2.6.18-194.el5 #1 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux), it only returns null. I'm using java 7 early access (1.7.0-ea-b84). I have to use this version due to functionality that isn't included in 1.6.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

It looks  like  it  requires  GLib.